# Any automated way to clone a data object?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bunch of simple data objects of different types (all properties are writable, no hidden state). Is there any automated way to clone such objects?
(yes, I know the way to clone them manually. Just don't want to ^_^)

Comment: Are these objects value types or reference types?

Comment: Why don't you want to clone them manually? Other than the obvious hassle...

Comment: What do you mean with `automated way`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning objects in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialize them in a (memory)stream and deserialize them back.

Comment: I found out, that this costs a lot of performance. Just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Serializing and deserializing would clone your object. Of course, the object would need to be serializable.

```
public static T Clone<T>(T source) 
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to implement IClonable interface in all objects but in case that objects developed not by you its not appropriate way for you.

The second way ( most universal in my opinion) is to use reflection:

```
    public T CommonClone<T>(T Source)
    {
        T ret = System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        Type typeDescr = typeof(T);

        if (typeDescr.IsClass != true)
        {
            ret = Source;
            return ret;
        }

        System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fi = typeDescr.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public); 

        for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
        {
            fi[i].SetValue(ret, fi[i].GetValue(Source));
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The code above will copy both public and private fields. If you need to cope only public ones, just remove `BindingFlags.NonPublic` from `GetFields` method call.
This way not specified any limitation on objects which can use. Its working both for classes and structures.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Web.Helpers;

public static T Clone<T>(T source)
{
    return Json.Decode<T>(Json.Encode(source));        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might see this 
[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)
Take a look at second answer. I use it all the time and it works great. The only drawback of this solution is the fact that class must be serializable